# How to import csv file to mysql more faster codeigniter

Tags: php, file, codeigniter, csv, import

Its working but when I import big files almost 2500+ lines in CSV files it load/import slowly and its say's error but some files are inserting ,some are not. And my question is there way to make it faster importing? I see in file But i don't get it how to use it.

Code:

```
    function convert_csv($id){
                if (empty($id)) redirect("contracts");
                $config['upload_path']   = './files/contracts-csv/'; 
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'csv';   
                $config['max_size']      = '4096';      
                $config['overwrite']     =  TRUE;

                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                $this->upload->display_errors('', '');

                if (!$this->upload->do_upload("csv_file")) {
                      echo $this->upload->display_errors(); die();
                      $this->data['error'] = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                } else {
                    $upload_result = $this->upload->data();
                    $upload_result = $this->upload->data(); 
                    $this->load->library('csvreader');
                    $result =   $this->csvreader->parse_file("./files/contracts-csv/".$upload_result['file_name']);
                    $date_today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                        foreach ($result as $v) {
                            $this->contract_items->add_serial($v,$id,$date_today);
                        }
                }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `set_time_limit(0)` in the beginning of your script ? It would not be faster, but it will execute entierly.

Comment: where do i need to add that? before my if(empty...)?

Comment: its running the same....

Answer (score 0):

Use [MySQL transactions in CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/transactions.html), it will speed up everything a lot (eg. make chunks of 500 items and insert them in one transaction).

But if it ends with error it looks like the problem might be somewhere else. 2500 isn't that much.

Comment: is not something error i think its because of too slow loading maybe 2600 files insert but the total files is 2800 and when 2600+ something its show error that "This webpage is not available"

Comment: Ok, so try to use transactions, I'm sure it will help a lot with processing speed.

Comment: is This correct?                                                $this->db->trans_start();
$this->db->set('contract_id', $id);
$this->db->set('date_inserted', $today);  
$this->db->insert($this->table, $data,$id,$today);
$this->db->trans_complete();

Answer (score 0):

each iteration for line in csv does the next things:

- build insert sql
- send it to db layout
- get response

you can try to build bulk sql like:

```
insert into table_name (f1, f2, f3) values ("val1", "val2", "val3"), ("val2_1", "val2_2", "val2_3"),...
```

about 100-200 `'("val1", "val2", "val3")'` blocks it should be faster, but I dont know how about codeigniter cache and other things...

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap it up in an [insert_batch](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#insert) query.

```
$your_data = array();
foreach ($result as $v) {
    $your_data[] = array(
        'v' => $v,
        'id' => $id,
        'date_today' => $today,
    );
);

$this->db->insert_batch('your_table_name', $your_data);
```

This will run the entire thing as a single query. Which should be faster than multiple queries. The exact code is up to you, as I don't know `$this->contract_items->add_serial` does.

Comment: im already trying this but i have two columns in csv file that is not indicated in there.

Comment: This is not the same as the code snippet you have pasted in a comment to @Martin's answer. Can you update your post with more details of your code, instead of us trying to fumble for straws?